# SSIS package failure when executed in windows task schedule

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, dtexec

I have three SSIS packages to sync data from SharePoint to SQL Server, I have put them in task schedule to run daily, but one or two of them failure sometimes.

The error message from task schedule is

> action "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" with return code 2147942401"

And my task is running using a service account:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /F E:\SSIS\Package.dtsx /Conf E:\SSIS\config.dtsConfig
```

If I uncheck the Run whether user logged on or not, then all goes fine.
It seems the package can't connect to the SQL Server that I config in `config.dstConfig` when failure. The failure also cause my db account been lock out.
But why only one or two package failure, not all?
And why everything goes fine if I run manually?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The service account needs 'Log on as a service' privilege to run scheduled jobs when a user is not logged on. You can try granting the  privilege and check. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc794944(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

After much work, I found out the schedule task fail because the SSIS package validation failed before run. It's not a permission issue. But still no idea why only fail in task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this workaround, it think it will solve your issue:

1. Instead of putting the full file path in the program/script textbox, use the Start in (Optional) field to put the folder that the `dtExec` file is actually in - Like so:

[image]

2. Check 'Run with highest privileges' Checkbox.

[image]

**References**

- https://blogfodder.co.uk/posts/win-2008-task-scheduler-with-return-code-1-0x1/